# Accessing msi filename from within msi file

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield

Is it possible to obtain the filename of an msi file from inside the msi file (when using either install shield or wix)?  I am looking for an easy solution to a problem I am trying to solve and was going to key off of the msi filename not being "x".

I have an existing msi file that I need to run silently and only accepts one command line parameter.  I need this change fairly quickly and am just researching my options.  Changing the name of the msi file would be a neat way to change the behavior of the install.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty weird request but OriginalDatabase Property will get you the full path.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you do key off the filename, generally the name during maintenance or removal may  not match the original install name. Instead it will be using a cached file with an arbitrary name.